# In JetBrains Rider, how to remove outputs or turn outputs into <1 internal line> in Console?

Tags: console, rider, jetbrains-rider

Is there any way I can remove the whole path from showing every time I run a program?
Wanted to remove this Path :

> C:\Users\14666\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\Rider\ch-0\222.4459.9\plugins\dpa\DotFiles\JetBrains.DPA.Runner.exe --handle=4660 --backend-pid=16976 --detach-event-name=dpa.detach.4660 C:/Users/14666/RiderProjects/Solution1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp1.exe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fpOn.png)

remove this annoying output or turn it into <1 internal line>

Comment: No, there is no such option in Rider. You can  try to file an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/